# Lyrics for Backyard Superheroes - Face it

Tags: lyrics

Here is the song [on YouTube](https://youtu.be/mvmxuNpk0_w).

I can't find the lyrics anywhere so I decided to write down what I have so far and you might be able to help me.

```
You’ve got wake up _____________
Only ten more minutes won't do me no harm
I'm in the red light and I'm going to be late
For my dead end job with the people I hate

Whatever happened to the people like me 
Working on dead end jobs ___________
Till they get by, man I don't have a choice
I can't say it any louder 'cause I'm losing my voice

Face it, I'm gonna spend all my time
With a case of cheap beer and a _______ (box full of wine)
I'm drinking all night just to get through the day
Got keep my ______ before drinking away

(Chorus)

 _______ backwards just to stay on my feet
Maybe this 9 to 5 just wasn't for me
Why’d I spend time doing something I hate
When I can stand here screaming at the edge of the stage

 (Verse)
(Chorus)
(Solo)
(Chorus)
(Verse)

With you!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote this song, so I may be able to help (hope it's not too late)!

Gotta wake up, snooze the alarm
Only ten more minutes won't do me no harm
I'm hitting red lights and I'm gonna be late
For my dead end job with the people I hate

Whatever happened to the people like me 
Working dead end jobs ending up in the street
How do they get by? Man I don't have a choice
I can't say it any louder 'cause I'm losing my voice

Face it, gonna spend all my time
With a case of cheap beer and a box full of wine
I'm drinking all night just to get through the day
Got keep my spirits before drinking away

(Chorus)

Keep moving backwards just to stay on my feet
Maybe this 9 to 5 just wasn't for me
Why spend time doing something I hate
When I can stand here screaming at the edge of the stage

Answer (score 4):

> You've got wake up, *snooze the alarm*

---

> Working on dead end jobs *ending up in the street*

---

> Got keep my *spirits up* before drinking away

---

> *Moving* backwards just to stay on my feet

---

The 'box full of wine' you heard seems right (but note: I'm not a native speaker).